# Best apporach to auto save dynamically created controls?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

### What I want to do

I have a .aspx webpage that displays dynamically created controls, mostly checkboxes, labels, textboxes. Controls are inside a PlaceHolder within a Repeater. What I want to do is to auto save the changes.

I have been reading a lot to find how I should go about, and I believe I have the following options.

- Auto save periodically using SetInterval
- Save when changes are made

### Problem

Right now I am trying to do the latter option and it does automatically save, but as many other people mentioned in the readings, it flickers and tabbing is frustrating because it loses the focus.

I have tried with AutoPostBack and it works, but again it's not so user friendly because of flickering and tabbing issues.

I have also tried with JQuery AJAX function and it works, but the same problems in usability. Since I am very new to AJAX, I'm not sure if it's a good practice to use `ScriptManager` and `UpdatePanel` for each control in the repeater.

### Question

To auto save values in dynamically created controls and avoid flickering and tabbing problems(lose focus, etc), what approach should I take?

Answer (score 0):

Things always take time, but you could use a little javascript with some page scripting and a service.

Use a Toolkitscriptmanager with Ajax service reference to another asmx, which will handle the calls needed to save stuff.

```
    <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"
        EnablePageMethods ="true" >
          <Services>
             <asp:ServiceReference  path="saveMyvalues.asmx" />
           </Services>
    </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

Then in some javascript, when your autosave timer triggers; pass the values to save to the asmx page which will handle the saving of the value....

something like...

```
   function saveAsingleTextbox(sndr){
          saveMyvalues.saveATextBox(sndr.id, sndr.value);

   }
```

You would need the script to walk all your controls or target each...

But a better way is to selectively trigger individual items as they are changed...

You can do this by adding triggers as the page loads...

```
  <asp:TextBox ID="tb_FirstName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>


   Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

      If IsPostBack = False Then
          tb_FirstName.Attributes.Add("onChange", "saveAsingleTextbox(this);") 
      End If

   End Sub
```

Thus the Javaxscript trigger is added to the textbox to call the function which deliver its value to the ASMX page which save it on a change...

Comment: thank you for the advice. I will read about `ToolkitScriptManager` and try your approach!